# Is it possible to send data from node.js express to front-end html without refreshing the page?

Tags: html, node.js, express, accordion

Now I have a page showing all meetings with collapsible accordions. In the beginning all the meetings are collapsed. Then when I click on the meeting button (which is named as 'Audio' in the screenshot), a request containing the meeting id is send to the node.js express and meeting details are retrieved from the database and returned by express to the same html page. To show the meeting details, the previously collapsed panel will be displayed.

Below is the screenshot for the collapsed meetings. The first two columns are for meeting codes as well as meeting names.

[image]

So basically it is calling express from the front-end by routing, and from the express only data but not the full html is returned and the js file of the html will be dealing those data and display them in the panel.

Is there any way for node.js express to send only data to the front-end html without refreshing the page?

Answer (score 1):

There is a possibility, yes, through AJAX, you just have to apply ajax together with node (express).
When you do a front a back ajax it returns you the data without reloading the page
Fonts:

```
https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp
https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX_(programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o)
```